# Retrieve data using outer join

Tags: sql, inner-join, outer-join, right-join

I wrote the following query to fetch the rows from `examPeriod` that match rows inside `EXAMCENTERWORKINGDAYS` based on the condition `Eep.[tpId]=ecwd.[TRAININGPERIODID]`

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT ep.[id]
FROM [LMS17_ARU_backup_201402080000].[dbo].[examperiod]ep
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT ecwd.[trainingperiodid]
   FROM [LMS17_ARU_backup_201402080000].[dbo].[examcenterworkingdays]ecwd
   WHERE ecwd.[value] <> 0
     AND ecwd.[trainingperiodid]IS NOT NULL)ecwd ON ep.[tpid] = ecwd.[trainingperiodid]
```

The trouble is that the select statement inside the bracket after the `right join`  retrieves only 95 rows and when I execute the query it returns 324 rows. I expected all the queries to return 95 rows, i.e I want to get `ep.[id]` from `[examPeriod]` table from the 95 rows returned from the nested select when `ep.[tpId]=ecwd.[TRAININGPERIODID]`

Sorry if it was silly question

Comment: You have multiple rows because there are multiple tpID's per training period ID

Comment: I think your `RIGHT` join is multiplexing your query results. That is for one value of ep.tdid you have multiple values of TRAININGPERIODID. Try validating this with actual values...